# Search for a value anywhere in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This seems like a simple question, but I couldn't find it asked before ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42386629/pandas-find-index-of-value-anywhere-in-dataframe) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32037802/find-target-values-in-pandas-dataframe) are close but the answers aren't great).

The question is: if I want to search for a value *somewhere* in my df (I don't know which column it's in) and return all rows with a match.

What's the most Pandaic way to do it? Is there anything better than:

```
for col in list(df):
    try:    
        df[col] == var
        return df[df[col] == var]
    except TypeError:
        continue
```

?

Comment: If there is more than 1 match, what do you want to return?

Comment: all rows with a match

Comment: @coldspeed really? "pandaic" over "pandorable"? ;)

Comment: Well, "pandaic" is what I've known the pandas devs to call it (eg Andy Hayden), but you are free to call it as you please, I'm sure synonyms are allowed :D

Comment: From 2020, this should now henceforth be called `Pandemic` over "Pandaic" or "Pandorable".

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You can perform equality comparison on the entire DataFrame:

```
df[df.eq(var1).any(1)]
```

Answer (score 34):

You should using `isin` , this is return the column , is want row check cold' answer :-)

```
df.isin(['bal1']).any()
A        False
B         True
C        False
CLASS    False
dtype: bool
```

Or

```
df[df.isin(['bal1'])].stack() # level 0 index is row index , level 1 index is columns which contain that value 
0  B    bal1
1  B    bal1
dtype: object
```

Comment: Guess this will need to be `df[df.isin(['bal1']).any(1)]`

Comment: This should be the correct answer, really...is the other one faster or something?

Comment: the `.stack()` is quite useful and a LOT more informative too

Answer (score 3):

You can try the code below:

```
import pandas as pd
x = pd.read_csv(r"filePath")
x.columns = x.columns.str.lower().str.replace(' ', '_')
y = x.columns.values
z = y.tolist()
print("Note: It take Case Sensitive Values.")
keyWord = input("Type a Keyword to Search: ")
try:
    for k in range(len(z)-1):
        l = x[x[z[k]].str.match(keyWord)]
        print(l.head(10))
        k = k+1
except:
    print("")
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution which will return the actual column you need.

```
df.columns[df.isin(['Yes']).any()]
```

Answer (score 0):

Minimal solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def locate_in_df(df, value):
    a = df.to_numpy()
    row = np.where(a == value)[0][0]
    col = np.where(a == value)[1][0]
    return row, col
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).